# Combine normal form with Dropzone

Tags: php, forms, upload, dropzone.js

I am creating a drop zone form using dropzone.js. I firstly set the form up to automatically upload the file this worked fine, but I adapted the form to work only when the user submitted the data,  i added file called custom_dropzone.js and the form appeared to work but the files never got uploaded to the folder.

HTML CODE (index.php)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<head>   
<link href="css/dropzone.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="dropzone.min.js"></script> 
<script src="custom_dropzone.js"></script>
```

```
 <!-- Now setup your input fields -->
 <input type="email" name="username" />
 <input type="password" name="password" />

 <button type="submit">Submit data and files!</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

upload.php

```
<?php
$ds          = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;  //1

$storeFolder = '../upload_test/uploads';   //2

if (!empty($_FILES)) {


 $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];          //3             

 $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;  //4

 $targetFile =  $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name'];  //5


$allowed =  array('gif','png' ,'jpg');
$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if(!in_array($ext,$allowed) ) {
echo 'error';
}

move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile); //6

}
?>
```

NEW JS custom.dropzone.js which seems to break the upload.php function

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = { // The camelized version of the ID of the form       element

  // The configuration we've talked about above
  autoProcessQueue: false,
  uploadMultiple: true,
  parallelUploads: 3,
  maxFiles: 3,
  previewsContainer: ".dropzone-previews",

  accept: function(file, done) {
    console.log("uploaded");
    done();
   },

  init: function() {
  this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file){
    alert("No more files please!");
  });
},

// The setting up of the dropzone
init: function() {
  var myDropzone = this;

  // First change the button to actually tell Dropzone to process the queue.
  this.element.querySelector("button[type=submit]").addEventListener("click",   function(e) {
    // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    myDropzone.processQueue();
   });

   // Listen to the sendingmultiple event. In this case, it's the sendingmultiple event instead
   // of the sending event because uploadMultiple is set to true.
   this.on("sendingmultiple", function() {
  // Gets triggered when the form is actually being sent.
  // Hide the success button or the complete form.
   });
   this.on("successmultiple", function(files, response) {
  // Gets triggered when the files have successfully been sent.
  // Redirect user or notify of success.
  });
  this.on("errormultiple", function(files, response) {
  // Gets triggered when there was an error sending the files.
  // Maybe show form again, and notify user of error
  });
 }

}
```

thanks for a lll your help. I just need the file to be uploaded, every thing else seems to work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With dropzone it seems that you do not need 
 method='post' 
 enctype='multipart/form-data'
 like what was mentioned by Shankar … but thank you

I resolved this by commenting out the below line of js from custom_dropzone.js
//uploadMultiple: true,

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add `enctype='multipart/form-data'` to your **`<form>`** as an attribute and the method type as **`POST`**.

Add like this..

```
 <form id="my-awesome-dropzone" method='post' class="dropzone" action="upload.php" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```

Comment: I tried that and though I agree you are correct the file still does not get uploaded. Thanks any other ideas

Comment: Try to `var_dump($_POST)` on your `upload.php` and then see what's wrong.

Comment: I tried that before and just now. It returns nothing as if the upload.php file is completely ignored. I just tried linking the upload folder and the action="… with absolute paths but that did not help. It seems if i add the custom js the php function gets aborted